# How to retrieve innerHTML value of an HTML element in CefSharp.OffScreen

Tags: javascript, c#, html, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I try to retrieve innerHTML values of an website to export them to a file by using CefSharp. But, the program doesn't run the code line.

For example, I filter a search by entering data to an example website and click to search button in the code below.

```
private async Task InitializeChromium()
        {
            string dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            CefSettings s = new CefSettings();
            s.LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Disable;
            s.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-compositing", "1");
            s.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable webgl", "1");
            s.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("off-screen-rendering-enabled", "1");
            s.DisableGpuAcceleration();
            s.WindowlessRenderingEnabled = true;
            s.BrowserSubprocessPath = dir + "CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe";
            Cef.Initialize(s);
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
            browser.LoadUrlAsync("https://cars.com");
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
           
            panel1.Controls.Add(browser);
               
                browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded("document.getElementsByClassName('sds-text-field')[5].value=94596");
            MessageBox.Show("data entered");
                browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded("document.getElementsByClassName('sds-button')[0].click()");
            MessageBox.Show("clicked button. it forwards to search page now with the filter");
            var script = "document.getElementById('makes')[0].innerHTML;";
            MessageBox.Show("script defined");
var result = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
            MessageBox.Show("script works");
if (result.Success && result.Result != null)
{
    string innerHtmlValue = result.Result.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(innerHtmlValue);
}


        }
```

To understand which line is not work, I added messagebox outputs. "data entered", "clicked button", and "script defined" messagebox lines work. But when it goes to `var script = "document.getElementById('makes')[0].innerHTML;";` line, it is not running that line and the messagebox below is not showing up. It has no errors and javascript is fine but somewhat that line is an issue.

How can I fix and get a value from an html element?

Comment: You say `CefSharp.OffScreen` in your title yet the code you've posted looks like it's using `WinForms`. I'd suggest you use `DevTools` to debug your javascript and get a better understanding of what's going on. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging If your javascript execution performs a asyncronious task like a `fetch` then you will need to wait for execution to complete before you can perform your next action. You also aren't waiting for the page to Load. If you are using `OffScreen` then provide the actual code you are using.